# Connecting android app(android studio) to myphpadmin database(already on the server)

Tags: database, android, android-development

I have a website for admin and a mobile app for normal user. Both of them share a same database which is now on the cloud(The website for admin is already deployed with the database on the server). The way I use to connect to our local database for our mobile app is through PHP scripts which contains the necessary parameters. The problem now is I do not know how to connect my mobile app(it is not deployed yet) to the database(which is now on the server). Is there any way to guide me ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a php get or post to communicate with the server. You would have to create a url in your Android application to connect to the php script on the server. For example, assuming you have a script called push.php on the server, this would connect to login_url.com/push.phpYOURPOSTMESSAGEHERE:

```
//Pushes a line of data to the server
//Column reference: thing1, thing2, thing3, thing4, thing5
protected String push(String login_url, String[] params){
    login_url+="/push.php";

    try {
        //This has to be inside the try/catch
        URL url = new URL(login_url);

        //See column reference at top of method
        String col1 = params[1];
        String col2 = params[2];
        String col3=params[3];
        String col4=params[4];
        String col5=params[5];
  //      String col6=params[6]; //etc for more lines of data

        //Opens a connection to the specified URL and reserves input/output privileges
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

        //Opens a container for the data to transmit to the server
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        //Sends text in UTF-8 format, should be compliant with any SQL implementation
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        //Generates a string from the data
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("thing1","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(col1,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("thing2","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(col2,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("thing3","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(col3,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("thing4","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(col4,"UTF-8")+"&"
                +URLEncoder.encode("thing5","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(col5,"UTF-8");
        //Writes the data to the output and ships it over the http url connection
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();

        //Opens a container to receive input from the server
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
        String result="";
        String line="";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
            result += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        return result;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "push method or php error";
}
```